# SP2010 Content Editor: add text to paragraph by default

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to make the Content Editor (RichHtmlField) in SP2010 add newly inserted text to a paragraph (with the default paragraph style  ms-rteElement-P). I have changed said css class to how I want the body text to be formatted and I want to eliminate the step of selecting the Markup Styles -> Paragraph style manually when a user starts to add content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/65152576-9432-4d55-a2e1-c798975859d5

> Hi,
>
> You have to override the PrefixStyleSheet property of the RichHtmlField control.
>
> Here is some more information about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551040.aspx
>
> Hope this helps!
>
> Regards, Sjoukje

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way, but you could use JavaScript to always add default content to any content editor on a page. Another way would be to create your own WebPart deriving from the Content Editor WebPart, but that sure is a lot more work.